# Error with crontab running a jar file

Tags: java, bash, jar, cron

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with open jdk and crontab. I made a neat little Java application that does some cool stuff and exported it as a runnable jar file. I can run it from the command line just fine, but I needed something that would run the file once every day. So I wrote in a cron job to run a shell script that would actually invoke the jar file. The shell script works fine when run on its own and it looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/java -jar /root/proj/CoolStuff.jar
```

Works perfectly. So I added this to the crontab:

```
23 14 * * * /root/proj/runScript.sh > /root/proj/log.txt 2>&1
```

This does not run perfectly. In fact, it doesn't run. log.txt will come out saying "Error". Pretty nondescript, right? I've checked my environment variables, nothing fancy there. Is there anything else I might be missing? Any ideas as to where to go from here? Is there any way I can run this script everyday with ease?

Answer (score 0):

Check the execution permission on that file.

The cron is running with different permissions, not the one you got when logged in.

Also you try to access /root.
Try to relocate your script to another "non-root" directory.

Comment: I originally had all of the files in a non root dir, but I'm running these scripts from root's crontab. Also, all permissions are 777 on the files in question.

Answer (score 0):

See what the environment for you crontab looks like by commenting out your current `/usr/bin/java ..` and insert `set` on a line by its own.

Now from you command line do `set > tmpEnvVarList.txt` and compare with what you see in log.txt.

It's almost certainly that your .profile or .bash_rc (or other) is setting env vars that are not available to you crontab. You'll need to add `. .profile` etc to you script.

cbO's ideas are good too.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this seems like it will be the solution. Would it be as simple as exporting out all of the environment variables not present in the cron environment? I was actually exporting the PATH vars, but I didn't show it above.

Comment: Please do the experiment and see what the results are. I would try to figure out adding which `. $HOME/.profile, . $HOME/.bash_rc` etc would solve the problem. Then your  code will be resiliant to any changes you make to your environment. Also, you're script's header says `#!/bin/sh`. are you on linux or unix? If linux, why not user `#!/bin/bash` . Good luck.

Comment: I added '. .profile' to the script and captured the output from the cron job. I get 'stdin: is not a tty' now followed by less environment vars than I received after executing the script by hand...

Comment: That was caused by my crazy formatting in crontab. Currently experimenting with environment vars.

Comment: Turns out that this didn't work :( I added almost all of the environment variables and used .profile and .bashrc, but no luck. Still getting a nondescript 'Error' message.

Comment: exactly 'Error', no other text? That's weird. If there is any extra text, please update your question with that information. Good luck.